# You should not call getWriteableDatabase() from the application main thread

Tags: android, android-sqlite

While I was researching the method `getWriteableDatabase()` on developer.android.com, They stated the following:

"You should not call this method from the application main thread"

They didn't seem to give a reason as to why you should not call `getWriteableDatabase()` from the application main thread. Could someone explain to me why?

Comment: Because a database upgrade may take a long time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long operations should **NEVER** be called on the main thread (aka. UI Thread), as it locks the responsiveness of your app.

The main thread is responsible to handle user input and all the screen drawing. So if one operation is taking too long, your app will be frozen until it finishes, and for the user it'll seems like your app crashed.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWwMA-sdOgk) from Udacity explains it very well.

[image]

You can read more about `Thread` on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads).

Answer (score 1):

`getWriteableDatabase()` will always do a bit of disk I/O, and even a little bit of disk I/O is something to avoid on the main application thread where possible.

However, if `getWriteableDatabase()` triggers calls to `onCreate()` or `onUpgrade()` of your `SQLiteOpenHelper`, those could do a **lot** of disk I/O, and you really need to do that work on a background thread. Remember, your UI is frozen while you are tying up the main application thread.